# Reconverting 4 prong to 3 prong back to 4prong dryer cord

Tags: dryer, cord-and-plug

I have a 4 prong dryer outlet and a 3 prong plug that was converted from the original 4 prong plug. Can this be converted back to a 4 prong plug via diy? What would I need to do that? Would it be safe?

Comment: Should be okay since you going back to original setup.  Make sure ground is connected to dryer frame, not neutral.

Comment: Was the original 4-prong plug cut off the cord and a 3-prong plug attached? And now you want to attach a 4-prong plug to the cord? Do you want to reattach the original plug or do you have a new one with internal screw connections?

Comment: You generally get a whole new dryer cord, and then attach it per the dryer's instructions for the 4 wire connection.

Comment: Yeah @Ecnerwal that is probably what the OP meant, but the OP's wording suggested to me that she might be thinking of reusung the cord and replacing the plug only.  Just wanted clarification.

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, however you need to download the instructions

Get the dryer model number and google the instructions.

When someone doesn't have a safety ground wire, and sneakily attaches the ground to the neutral to fool testers, we call that "bootlegging ground".  From 1966-1996, due to appliance industry lobbying, dryers and ranges were legally allowed "no-ground" connections, and the dryer instructions explained how to bootleg ground off neutral.

When you convert (back) to 4-wire connection, you must find that bootleg strap, and remove it. The instructions will say how.

Comment: Many times the instructions are printed right on the back of the dryer, or on the cover for the cord attachment point.